# Laravel 4.1 Invalid request Unexpected EOF

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to install Laravel 4.1. After installed when i run php artisan serve I get this error:
Invalid request (Unexpected EOF). I have no idea why it's showing this error. I also have laravel 4.0 installed and it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Landed here after having this problem myself. Searching around, the error seems to be related to the network prediction feature of some browser (primarily Chrome). Disabling the feature, did the trick for me on Windows with php 5.4.9

Source: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60471

Comment: I had the same problem in Firefox and I found that disabling caching fixed the problem. I'm serving using the inbuilt artisan server and am running Laravel 5.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are updated the installation successfully.

Run this in your project directory.

```
composer update
```

Comment: It's working on browser. But still I am getting these error in my terminal:                                                          [Fri Dec 13 10:54:36 2013] ::1:50914 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

Comment: I think, it may be based on some cache issues. I am also got some errors like this, when I tried to access ``cms``, it's getting result of ``cmspro``. When restarted system, it's working fine.

Comment: After I restart my mac I am still getting the same error: [Fri Dec 13 11:13:50 2013] ::1:49251 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)

Comment: Compare your ``artisan`` file with this https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan

Comment: try typing just `php -S localhost:8080` or something. See if the issue is with php or apache. Also you need to have php >=5.4. Does it correctly create a temporary web server at that address?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. I believe if you are serving with `artisan` you have to specify the port number like so:

```
./artisan serve --port=XXXX --host=whatever.com
```

The problem for me was I didn't set the `base` correctly. Make sure that in your file your `base` is set to be at this port as well. So for my case, I had to set my `index.html` to be

```
<base href="http://www.whatever.com:XXXX/" />
```

After I fixed that, it served correctly. Hope this helps.

EDIT: Oh and FYI make sure what you type in your browser is exactly the same as what you set your `base` to be. So that means you can't do `whatever.com:XXXX` and expect it to serve. You're gonna need to do `www.whatever.com:XXXX`. Life is frustrating sometimes.